# tikz cd not working in beamer

Tags: beamer, tikz-cd

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usepackage{times}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{epsfig, graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[framesassubsections]{beamerprosper}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\beamertemplatetransparentcovereddynamic
\newcommand{\tb}{\textbf}

%\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\{#1\}}

\title[Something]
{\large Something else}


\author[Nick Name]{{\bf{Name}}  \and \\
\vskip 0.5cm
\small{\inst{}\\ School of Mathematics\\ 
University}\\
}
\institute[University]{ \small{  }
}
\date{1st August 2019}

\colorlet{redshaded}{red!25!bg}
\colorlet{shaded}{black!25!bg}
\colorlet{shadedshaded}{black!10!bg}
\colorlet{blackshaded}{black!40!bg}

\colorlet{darkred}{red!80!black} \colorlet{darkblue}{blue!80!black}
\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!80!black}

\def\radius{0.96cm}
\def\innerradius{0.85cm}

\def\softness{0.4}
\definecolor{softred}{rgb}{1,\softness,\softness}
\definecolor{softgreen}{rgb}{\softness,1,\softness}
\definecolor{softblue}{rgb}{\softness,\softness,1}

\definecolor{softrg}{rgb}{1,1,\softness}
\definecolor{softrb}{rgb}{1,\softness,1}
\definecolor{softgb}{rgb}{\softness,1,1}
\definecolor{pink}{rgb}{1,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{rosa}{rgb}{1.0,0.5,1.0}




\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\frame{
\[\begin{tikzcd}
F(u) \arrow[dd, "\eta(u)"'] \arrow[rr, "F(\alpha)"] &  & F(v) \arrow[dd, "\eta(v)"] \\
                                                    &  &                            \\
G(u) \arrow[rr, "G(\alpha)"']                       &  & G(v)                      
\end{tikzcd}\]
}
\end{document}
```

This is the minimal working example. Please let me know why this is not working.

Comment: I borrowed this code (some years ago and used it atmost 2 times) from some one. Please see if you can make this code cleaner..

Comment: In addition to egregs answer just wanted to mention why it fails: tikzcd has to change what & means. However you cannot do that when being used as an argument to a macro, which is why the env version of frame is preferable (plus the env based code is so much easier to read). Note you can make tikzcd work inside the arg to a macro by using the alternative `\&` syntax. It is just not with it here.

Comment: @daleif  Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have, of course, to load `tikz-cd`. Then you have two options: either declare the frame to be `fragile` or use `ampersand replacement` as shown below.

Avoid the syntax `\frame{...}` that has less options than `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}`.

```latex
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},xcolor={table}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\useinnertheme{rounded}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % <- really?
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[framesassubsections]{beamerprosper}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\beamertemplatetransparentcovereddynamic

\title[Something]{\large Something else}


\author[Nick Name]{{\bf{Name}}  \and \\
\vskip 0.5cm
\small{\inst{}\\ School of Mathematics\\ 
University}\\
}
\institute[University]{ \small{  }
}
\date{1st August 2019}

\colorlet{redshaded}{red!25!bg}
\colorlet{shaded}{black!25!bg}
\colorlet{shadedshaded}{black!10!bg}
\colorlet{blackshaded}{black!40!bg}

\colorlet{darkred}{red!80!black} \colorlet{darkblue}{blue!80!black}
\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!80!black}

\def\radius{0.96cm}
\def\innerradius{0.85cm}

\def\softness{0.4}
\definecolor{softred}{rgb}{1,\softness,\softness}
\definecolor{softgreen}{rgb}{\softness,1,\softness}
\definecolor{softblue}{rgb}{\softness,\softness,1}

\definecolor{softrg}{rgb}{1,1,\softness}
\definecolor{softrb}{rgb}{1,\softness,1}
\definecolor{softgb}{rgb}{\softness,1,1}
\definecolor{pink}{rgb}{1,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{rosa}{rgb}{1.0,0.5,1.0}




\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
F(u) \arrow[dd, "\eta(u)"'] \arrow[rr, "F(\alpha)"] &  & F(v) \arrow[dd, "\eta(v)"] \\
                                                    &  &                            \\
G(u) \arrow[rr, "G(\alpha)"']                       &  & G(v)                      
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
F(u) \arrow[dd, "\eta(u)"'] \arrow[rr, "F(\alpha)"] \&  \& F(v) \arrow[dd, "\eta(v)"] \\
                                                    \&  \&                            \\
G(u) \arrow[rr, "G(\alpha)"']                       \&  \& G(v)                      
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have removed the loading of `epsfig` (deprecated since 1993), `amsfonts` (that's already loaded by `amssymb`) and `graphics` (already loaded by `graphicx`).

Are you sure your files are encoded with Latin-1? If they are, it's time to move towards UTF-8.

Comment: I thank you for the code..  I don’t know what is Latin-1.. how do I change to UTF-8?.

Comment: If this code (anything before \begin{document}) can be made better, please do let me know... I think this code is not clean...